# Date from string in format javascript google apps script

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

In my web app user needs to fill the fields like date and time. 
In date they can enter a date in a format:
d/m/yy 
or 
dd/mm/yy 
(unfortunately I can't control how exactly user will enter it)

And they can also pick a time from the drop-down list:
08:00am,8.30am, 09:00am,.... , 05:00 pm

Now, I am trying to convert time and date strings  it into a valid date object using function below, but I am getting "Date isInvalid Date" output. 
How should I proceed with it?

```
  var timeStartString ="1970/01/01 "+ "10:00am";
  var st1 =createDate("1/12/2013",timeStartString); 
  Logger.log("Date is"+st1);

 function createDate(dateString,timeString)
    {
      var eventDate  = new Date(dateString);
      var eventTime  = new Date(timeString)

      message +="Date String:"+dateString + " timeString "+timeString;

      eventTime.setFullYear(eventDate.getFullYear());
      eventTime.setDate(eventDate.getDate());
      eventTime.setMonth(eventDate.getMonth()); 

      return eventTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look into using the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library, which makes date parsing and manipulation in JavaScript a bit easier. More information on how to use it in Apps Script [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/103231502413952116096/posts/ThnVjUgU3E9). If the date format is consistent, then you can use a custom format string to parse it.

```
var date = moment('1970/01/01 10:00am', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mma').toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Date class won't recognize the time if am or pm is directly attatched to the time.  For example `new Date("1/12/2013 10:00am")` will return `Invalid Date`, whereas `new Date("1/12/2013 10:00 am")` will return `Sat Jan 12 2013 22:00:00`.  It's a subtle difference, but that's the way the parser is built.  You shouldn't need the `createDate` method at all if you concatenate the date with the properly formatted time string.